# how to convert auto height to px

Tags: javascript

In javascript (Chrome), I get the height of an element, in this case an image:

```
var computedStyle =  window.getComputedStyle(img_element).getPropertyValue("height")
```

If this is "auto" is there some easy way to get this value in px? Would it be the same as its parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var height = img_element.naturalHeight;
```

But I wasn't aware that `getComputedStyle()` ever returned non-pixel measurements.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be an error on my part. a and span tags can have height = auto, but not an img. Haven't tested naturalHeight so marking answer correct for the second part of the answer.